# join between two database values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables. A category table with the columns: `name` and `category`. And an entry table with the columns: `entry` and `entry_name`. The `name` and `entry_name` columns share the same names (foreign key relationship). I could like to do a count of all the entries made in the entry table but only for a specific category from the category table (e.g. count and group by descending only for category 3)

I've tried some basic joins with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your tries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a result with your entries and categories, then filter with where:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM entries e
LEFT JOIN categories cat
ON e.entry_name = cat.name
WHERE cat.category = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(1)
  from caterogy c inner join entry e on (c.name = e.entry_name)
 where c.category = 'SPECIFIC_CAT'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CATEGORY c
INNER JOIN ENTRY e 
ON c.name = e.entry_name
WHERE c.category = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(c.name), c.category
FROM CATEGORY c
INNER JOIN ENTRY e 
ON c.name = e.entry_name
GROUP BY c.category
ORDER BY c.category DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(category)
FROM Entries
JOIN Categories
ON Categories.name = Entries.entry_name
WHERE Categories.category = 3
```